# How to tell if HTML5 video tag source supports CORS?

Tags: html, video, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using a HTML5 canvas to take a screen shot of a video tag.   This works about 80% of the time on Chrome.  The other 20% of the time I'm getting "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported" error.  I'm assuming this is because the video source doesn't support CORS.

I've tried adding the attribute 'videoTag.attr('crossorigin', 'anonymous');' to the video tag but that doesn't seem to help.

So my question is there anyway to tell if the video tag supports CORS?

```
    // Get handles on the video element
    var video = videoContainer[0];

    var canvas = jQuery('#temp-canvas')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 640;
    canvas.height = 360;

    // Define the size of the rectangle that will be filled (basically the entire element)
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 390);

    // Grab the image from the video
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //return the url so we can use it 
    //Failed to execute toDataURL exception thrown here
    imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: I think I do remember this error on videos had something to do about the file format to be drawn (something like DRM in mp4) Not sure though, and can't do the search about it right now...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're testing for an error condition rather than a browser feature, you can use a `try-catch` block.